# NullPointerException when showing a ViewPager a second time

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I am using a `ViewPager` fragment which has two fragments as children. This works great, however when I replace the `ViewPager` fragment by another fragment and replace this fragment by the `ViewPager` fragment my application crashes with the following `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:667)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:211)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1319)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:13756)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2888)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:13734)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:468)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1094)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

My `ViewPager` fragment consists of the following source code instanciating the two child fragments in case they are null. Furthermore, the `ViewPagerAdapter` implementation is instanciated and assigned to the `ViewPager`.

```
public class ConnectionPasswordViewPagerFragment extends Fragment
{
    private ViewPager vpConnectionPassword;
    private ConnectionPasswordViewPagerAdapter paConnectionPassword;
    private ConnectionPasswordGeneratorMACAddress passwordGeneratorMACAddress;
    private ConnectionPasswordGeneratorSerialNumber passwordGeneratorSerialNumber;

    public ConnectionPasswordViewPagerFragment()
    {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if ((this.passwordGeneratorSerialNumber == null) && (this.passwordGeneratorMACAddress == null))
    {
        this.passwordGeneratorMACAddress = new ConnectionPasswordGeneratorMACAddress();
        this.passwordGeneratorSerialNumber = new ConnectionPasswordGeneratorSerialNumber();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connection_password_view_pager, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    /*if (this.paConnectionPassword == null)
    {*/
        this.paConnectionPassword = new ConnectionPasswordViewPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager(), this.getActivity(), this.passwordGeneratorMACAddress, this.passwordGeneratorSerialNumber);
    //}
    this.vpConnectionPassword = (ViewPager) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vpConnectionPassword);
    this.vpConnectionPassword.setAdapter(this.paConnectionPassword);
    }
}
```

The `ViewPagerAdapter` shown below implementation keeps the reference to the child fragments in an `ArrayList` and implements the metods `getItem()`, `getCount()` as well as `getPageTitle()`. The class `ViewPagerFragment` simply extends the support `Fragment` class and provides the abstract method `getPageTitleStringID()` implemented by the child fragments.

```
public class ConnectionPasswordViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private static final byte NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS = (byte) 2;

    private ArrayList<ViewPagerFragment> childFragments;
    private Activity displayActivity;

    public ConnectionPasswordViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentMgm, Activity displayAct, ConnectionPasswordGeneratorMACAddress generatorMACAddress, ConnectionPasswordGeneratorSerialNumber generatorSerialNumber)
    {
    super(fragmentMgm);

    this.childFragments = new ArrayList<>(ConnectionPasswordViewPagerAdapter.NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS);
    this.setDisplayActivity(displayAct);
    if (generatorMACAddress != null)
    {
        this.childFragments.add(generatorMACAddress);
    }
    if (generatorSerialNumber != null)
    {
        this.childFragments.add(generatorSerialNumber);
    }
    }

    public Activity getDisplayActivity()
    {
    return this.displayActivity;
    }

    public void setDisplayActivity(Activity value)
    {
    this.displayActivity = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
    return this.childFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
    return ConnectionPasswordViewPagerAdapter.NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
    return this.getDisplayActivity().getString(this.childFragments.get(position).getPageTitleStringID());
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the issue by simply creating the fragment containing the view pager every time I call the support fragment manager's `replace` method.

```
public void onSwitchToConnectionPasswordGenerator(View clickedView)
{
    this.fragConnectionPassword = new ConnectionPasswordViewPagerFragment();
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flFragmentContainer, this.fragConnectionPassword).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: I am using a friend's account, but can you take a look at my question? I am having more or less the exact situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213051/no-indication-as-to-where-npe-could-occur?noredirect=1#comment71590739_42213051

Answer (score 2):

I think your Viewpager is in Fragment, and this fragment have setRetainInstance set to true (i have this error too when i try to retain the parent fragment)

Comment: Thanks! I suppose you mean that I should call `setRetainInstance(false)`. Where should I make this method call?

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to you can check for `FragmentManager` to get Fragment if its there, if not then create a new instance as follows:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag("YourFragmentName");

if(fragment == null)
  fragment = new YourFragment();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(Your_Fragmnet_Container_Layout_id, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
fragmentTransaction.commit;
```